# How can I pass values for sap.m.P13nItem in XML view

Tags: sapui5

I have a `sap.m.P13nItem` that I set it in XML view by `CustomData` like the following:

```
    <core:CustomData key="p13nData"
        value='\{"columnKey": "StdNo", 
                 "leadingProperty": "StdNo", 
                 "sortProperty": "StdNo", 
                 "filterProperty": "StdNo", 
                 "columnIndex":"11", 
                 "type": "empty string", 
                 "maxLength": "{ path: &#39;/#MySet/StdNo/@maxLength&#39;, formatter:&#39;.formatter.fnStrToInt&#39; }", 
                 "values": ["", "O", "I"] 
                }'/>
```

This `StdNo` is of type `Edm.Boolean`.

```
<Property Name="StdNo" Type="Edm.Boolean" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Standard No." sap:creatable="false"/>
```

Everything works fine, just as `P13nItem` only supports text, numeric or date as the type based on this [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.P13nItem) and does not have any type for boolean I want to pass the array of values for that again based on the same [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.P13nItem).

What I had passed as the values array does not put any effect on my p13n item.

Any suggestion regarding how I can pass this array in XML view!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `type` property to `boolean` to show a list of `Yes/No` for boolean attributes.

```
<core:CustomData key="p13nData"
    value='\{"columnKey": "StdNo", 
             "leadingProperty": "StdNo", 
             "sortProperty": "StdNo", 
             "filterProperty": "StdNo",
             "type": "boolean",
             "values": ["", "O", "I"] 
            }'/>
```

[Here is a picture from the original values for boolean drop down box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwq2O.jpg)

[image: Here is a picture of how we can set the values for boolean type drop down]

Comment: Nice. Thanks. At least I can see the default values for boolean values. It is so disappointing that SAP documentation is not up to date.

Comment: Yes, That is right. Sometime, you will find inconsistent documentations that easily can end you up with waisting a couple of hours.

Comment: I discovered my code regarding values array was correct, therefore I edited your answer.